# Label error in tkinter while exiting window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label, clock

I am trying to make a digital clock through python tkinter .My code is

```
import tkinter,time

def exiter():
    root.destroy()

root=tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Digital Clock")
root.geometry("340x100")
root.resizable(False,False)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",exiter)

def time_setter():
    hr=tkinter.Label(root,font=('k',60,'bold'),text=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    hr.grid(row=0,column=0)

    

while True:
    root.update()
    time_setter()
```

After I close the window I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Tanmay Daga\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Clock-Tkinter\digital_clock.py", line 20, in <module>
    time_setter()
  File "c:\Users\Tanmay Daga\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Clock-Tkinter\digital_clock.py", line 13, in time_setter
    hr=tkinter.Label(root,font=('k',60,'bold'),text=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3145, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2569, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "label" command: application has been destroyed
```

How do I break the loop when the window is closed.
How do I know when the window is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
from time import strftime

def clock_tick():
    string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
    lbl.config(text=string)#set the text
    lbl.after(1000, time)#updater 
    
root=Tk() 
lbl = Label(root, font=('calibri', 40, 'bold'),
            background='purple',
            foreground='white')
lbl.pack(anchor = 'center')
clock_tick() 
root.title("Digital Clock")
root.geometry("340x100")
root.resizable(False,False)
root.mainloop() #this is the loop you are looking for instead of the while loop
```

The loop is wrong. For tkinter there is a built in loop that is much better to use.  Exiting this with the X will provide a clean exit if you set the loop up  by using root.mainloop(). Here is a good example of what you are trying to do
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-create-a-digital-clock-using-tkinter/

Comment: As `time` is built-in module, better not using it as function name.

Comment: You are right, I pulled most of this from geeks for geeks. I've changed it to not conflict with the built in module.